# How to Return Value of Radio Button

Tags: django, radio-button, return

I realize this should be a simple question, but I can't seem to get it to work and I've been googling for about an hour. I have a set of radio buttons defined in my HTML code here:

```
<h6>Axis Filter</h6>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for radio in form.axis_filter %}
            <div class="radio-inline">   
                {{radio}}   
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

And in my forms.py file here:

```
TIME_FILTER = [
        ('years','Years'),
        ('quarters','Quarters')
        ]
axis_filter= forms.CharField(label = 'axis_filter',widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=TIME_FILTER),initial = 'years')
```

Now I'm trying to get the selected value in my views.py using this:

```
request.GET.get('axis_filter',None)
```

I've also tried:

```
request.POST.get('axis_filter',None)
```

Each time I go to print the value however I get a value of 'none'. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Just to exclude basic mistakes (since you didn't include it in your code samples):

Are you putting your radio buttons inside form tags?

```
<form method="post">
    ... radio buttons and csrf_token ...
</form>
```